# currency convertor app not working

Tags: java, android, xml

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="edu.uncc.sbagursu.currencyconvertor.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:hint="Input Amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/inputAmount" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inputAmount"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/aud"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/aud"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked1"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/cad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cad"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked1"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/inr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/inr"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked1"/>

    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/convertTo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/radioGroup2" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inputAmount"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup3">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/usd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/usd"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked2"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/gbp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/gbp"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked2"/>


    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:text="@string/convert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:id="@+id/convertButton"
        android:onClick="onClickConvert"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/convertButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioGroup3"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />

    <Button
        android:text="Clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/convertButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/convertButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:id="@+id/clearButton" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
package com.example.shara.currencyconvertor;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    private RadioGroup grp1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
    private RadioGroup grp2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup3);


    private EditText inputAmt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputAmount);
    private final String inputText = inputAmt.getText().toString();
    private double inputAmount = Integer.parseInt(inputText);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.convertButton).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.clearButton).setOnClickListener(this);

        grp1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
            }
        });

        grp2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                RadioButton btn2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int radioId1 = grp1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        int radioId2 = grp2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        double result = 0;

        if(v.getId()==R.id.convertButton){

            if(radioId1 == R.id.aud){
                if(radioId2 == R.id.usd){
                    result = inputAmount*1.34;
                    Log.d("test", "Result is" +result);
                    txt.setText(""+result);
                }
                else if(radioId2 == R.id.gbp){
                    result = inputAmount*(0.83/1.34);
                    Log.d("test", "Result is" +result);
                    txt.setText(""+result);
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("test", "nothing here");

                }


            }

            if(radioId1 == R.id.cad){
                if(radioId2 == R.id.usd){
                    result = inputAmount*1.32;
                    Log.d("test", "Result is" +result);
                    txt.setText(""+result);
                }
                else if (radioId2 == R.id.gbp) {
                        result = inputAmount * (0.83 / 1.32);
                        Log.d("test", "Result is" + result);
                    txt.setText(""+result);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("test", "nothing here");
                }

            if(radioId1 == R.id.inr){
                if(radioId2 == R.id.usd){
                    result = inputAmount*68.14;
                    Log.d("test", "Result is" +result);
                    txt.setText(""+result);
                }
                else if(radioId2 == R.id.gbp){
                    result = inputAmount*(0.83/68.14);
                    Log.d("test", "Result is" +result);
                    txt.setText(""+result);
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("test", "nothing here");
                }

            }

        }

        else if(v.getId()== R.id.clearButton){

        txt.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately though everything seems right I am unable to get the app to run and the app crashes. Any help in resolving this is appreciated. I am a novice in android.

Updated with Logcat file:

```
    01-21 17:42:56.229 6017-6017/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
    01-21 17:42:56.244 6017-6023/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
    01-21 17:42:56.244 6017-6023/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
    01-21 17:42:56.278 6017-6017/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.shara.currencyconvertor-1/lib/x86
    01-21 17:42:56.278 6017-6017/? I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.shara.currencyconvertor, real application class is null.
    01-21 17:42:56.526 6017-6017/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.shara.currencyconvertor-1/lib/x86
    01-21 17:42:56.556 6017-6017/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    01-21 17:42:56.556 6017-6017/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
         Process: com.example.shara.currencyconvertor, PID: 6017
         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shara.currencyconvertor/com.example.shara.currencyconvertor.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:120)
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:151)
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31)
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55)
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:33)
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:203)
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:525)
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:193)
             at com.example.shara.currencyconvertor.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:15)
             at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
             at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
        01-21 17:47:56.701 6017-6017/com.example.shara.currencyconvertor I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6017 SIG: 9



LogCat after making changes:
01-21 18:33:57.523 11590-11590/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.shara.currencyconvertor, PID: 11590
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shara.currencyconvertor/com.example.shara.currencyconvertor.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
                                                       at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                       at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
                                                       at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
                                                       at com.example.shara.currencyconvertor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: `"... and the app crashes."` -- this tells us little that can help us to understand exactly what is going on. Please tell the specifics.

Comment: Will sharing my logs help?

Comment: It most certainly will.

Comment: updated with log file

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing the views before the onCreate has loaded. It makes sense you're getting a NullPointerException.

Try the changes here. Notice that all the views are being declared at the top but initialized in the OnCreate. The "inputText" can't be final, Unless you declare it inside the onCreate.

```
package com.example.shara.currencyconvertor;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private TextView txt;
    private RadioGroup grp1;
    private RadioGroup grp2;


    private EditText inputAmt;
    private String inputText;
    private double inputAmount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.convertButton).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.clearButton).setOnClickListener(this);

        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        grp1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
        grp2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup3);


        inputAmt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputAmount);
        inputText = inputAmt.getText().toString();
        inputAmount = Integer.parseInt(inputText);


        grp1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
            }
        });

        grp2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                RadioButton btn2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int radioId1 = grp1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        int radioId2 = grp2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        double result = 0;

        if(v.getId()==R.id.convertButton){

            if(radioId1 == R.id.aud){
                if(radioId2 == R.id.usd){
                    result = inputAmount*1.34;
                    Log.d("test", "Result is" +result);
                    txt.setText(""+result);
                }
                else if(radioId2 == R.id.gbp){
                    result = inputAmount*(0.83/1.34);
                    Log.d("test", "Result is" +result);
                    txt.setText(""+result);
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("test", "nothing here");

                }


            }

            if(radioId1 == R.id.cad){
                if(radioId2 == R.id.usd){
                    result = inputAmount*1.32;
                    Log.d("test", "Result is" +result);
                    txt.setText(""+result);
                }
                else if (radioId2 == R.id.gbp) {
                    result = inputAmount * (0.83 / 1.32);
                    Log.d("test", "Result is" + result);
                    txt.setText(""+result);
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.d("test", "nothing here");
            }

            if(radioId1 == R.id.inr){
                if(radioId2 == R.id.usd){
                    result = inputAmount*68.14;
                    Log.d("test", "Result is" +result);
                    txt.setText(""+result);
                }
                else if(radioId2 == R.id.gbp){
                    result = inputAmount*(0.83/68.14);
                    Log.d("test", "Result is" +result);
                    txt.setText(""+result);
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("test", "nothing here");
                }

            }

        }

        else if(v.getId()== R.id.clearButton){

            txt.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Sorry I just now noticed the XML.

You are tring to parse the content of the EditText when it's empty. You need to parse it after the use wrote something. If you dont wanna add a button, you can use:

```
inputAmt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            inputText = inputAmt.getText().toString();
            inputAmount = Integer.parseInt(inputText);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Still Crashing :(

Comment: Seems that you have a problem here: inputAmount = Integer.parseInt(inputText); What's in the textview?

Comment: it is declared as double and i changed it to Double.parseDouble as well.

Comment: the textview is a blank field which will display the result after conversion.